# Retrieving ID from sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Relating to my previous question, I want to retrieve the ID from the sqlite database created to pass it as data in an Intent putExtra() for using it as the id for pendingIntent.getActivity(). Currently, I am using queryNumEntries to set the id for each reminder added into the database from the following code in my DatabaseManager.class:

```
public long reminderCount(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sqlDB, DatabaseReminder.TABLE_NAME);
    }
```

and calling it in AddActivity.class

```
String remindId;
long RemID;
int remId;

RemID = databaseManager.reminderCount()+1;
remindId = String.valueOf(RemID);                
remId = Integer.parseInt(remindId);

private void sendUpdateAlarm() {
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateReminderActivity.class);
        updateIntent.putExtra("NotifID", remId);
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("DateTime", dateTimePicked);
        intent.putExtra("NotifID", remId);
        intent.putExtra("Title", titlePicked);
        intent.putExtra("Description", descriptionPicked);

        PendingIntent addIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, remId, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Date.parse(dateTimePicked), addIntent);
    }
```

I am confused if there is another method to retrieve the ID right when the entry is created aside from trying this.

Update:
In insert method for DatabaseManager.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddReminderActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("remindId", reminderID);
```

AddReminderActivity:

```
                RemID = getIntent().getLongExtra("remindId", 0);
//                Log.i(TAG, "remID: " + RemID);
//                = 0
                reminderId = String.valueOf(RemID);
//                Log.i(TAG, "reminderId: " + reminderId);
//                = 0
                remId = Integer.parseInt(reminderId);
//                Log.i(TAG, "reminder: " + remId);
//                = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused if there is another method to retrieve the ID right when the entry is created aside from trying this.

Yes, BUT it depends upon the definition of the table.

If the **id** is generated then when inserting the row (entry) and if using the convenience [SQLiteDatabase insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method (or the [insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method or the [insertWithOnconflict](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) method) then the long that is return will be the generated id or -1 if the row was not inserted.

An **id** will be generated if the column is defined using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. (see links below for an explanation)

- Note that only the INTEGER keyword has this effect. e.g. INT PRIMARY KEY will not work.
- PRIMARY KEY can be at the column level (as shown) or it can be at the TABLE level.
- for an explanation see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowids_and_the_integer_primary_key and also https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Using your method of assuming that the new id will be 1 greater than the number of rows in the table will not be accurate under a number of scenarios, such as if any row other than the last has been deleted.

A query less prone to resulting in another value would be to use `coalesce(max(id),0)` as this gets the highest id, irrespective of deleted rows.

- see https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#max_agg
- the coalesce function is used to ensure that 0 is returned in the case of NULL (empty table). see https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce

However using the max aggregate function, the value returned can also be incorrect, such as if rows are inserted with an **id** that is less than the highest. This is possible if

- the id value has been specified when inserting or
- the highest allowable *(9223372036854775807)* id has been used and AUTOINCREMENT has not been coded in the column definition (if AUTOINCREMENT has been coded then in the case that the highest allowable id has been used then an SQLITE_FULL error will result)

Comment: For the ID value inserted, I used without AUTOINCREMENT when creating the table and inserting an entry. Following your answer, aside from the use of coalesce() or max_agg(), would rawQuery work in fetching the id selected for each entry to be used as the id in pendingIntent?

Comment: @AmethystLilac no as a single statement/invocation, only the convenience methods do this as they do the additional work to retrieve the id (actually the rowid as even if you have no integer primary key specified it will return the rowid). However, you could use `rawQuery`, immediately after the insert (in a transaction with the insert to be safe), the insert could be using rawQuery or execSQL (the latter as no result set is returned from such an insert).

Comment: so after using 
'databaseManager.addReminder(titlePicked, descriptionPicked, timePicked, datePicked, dateTimePicked);'
do i call the rawQuery method immediately after this line specified in my DatabaseManager.class as well as a function?

Comment: @AmethystLilac that's not totally safe (probably is but potentially another row could be inserted/updated/deleted) but really I would suggest using the convenience insert method to insert, it does all that you need within a transaction thus locking out any other potential insert/update/delete. P.S. the above does not factor in `WITHOUT ROWID` tables (se https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)

Comment: following the insert method in my DatabaseManager.class as follows:
`
public void addReminder(String title, String definition, String remindertime, String reminderdate, String reminderdatetime){
        CV.put(DatabaseReminder.Title, title);
        long reminderID = sqlDB.insert(DatabaseReminder.TABLE_NAME, null, CV);

        if (reminderID > 0){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        sqlDB.close();
    }

so as long as the reminderID is not less than or equal to 0, would it still be unsafe?

Comment: @AmethystLilac as you are using the convenience method then **yes** as it's all done in a single transaction *(the only **extremely unlikely** issue would be if the id reached 9223372036854775807 AND a negative rowid/id existed (you'd have to force a negative rowid/id)  the id could be negative).*

Comment: upon using the convenience method, how would this make it possible to retrieve the ID from sqlite to be used in a pendingIntent for one specific alarm that is set? I still am a bit confused about this.

Comment: @AmethystLilac you don't need to get the value from SQLite, the convenience insert method returns the id (if it's an alias of the rowid, otherwise the rowid itself) as a long.  You can then set an intent extra with the id/long and then extract it from the passed intent.